# Disabling reliability features on an ephemeral ext4 filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, mkfs

I am using `cryptsetup` to create a new, temporary filesystem with a random, ephemeral key. This is an alternative to creating an encrypted swap file and using a giant tmpfs mount, as that would have far worse performance. Because the key (and thus filesystem) will be lost at poweroff, I have no need for any reliability features such as journaling, so I would like to turn them off to improve performance.

I am creating the filesystem with superblock backups, the journal, and checksumming disabled:

```
mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -E num_backup_sb=0 -O ^has_journal,^metadata_csum,^uninit_bg,sparse_super2 /dev/mapper/crypt
```

I also set the default mount options to decrease the frequency at which the dirty buffers are flushed:

```
tune2fs -o commit=3600 /dev/mapper/crypt
```

Are there any other reliability features I can disable or unsafe optimizations I can *enable*?

Comment: ssd / hd ? kernel >=5.10 ? typical workflow ? (random / sequential | read / writes )… well… you don't tell much…

Comment: @MC68020 I just want to disable reliability features that are irrelevant for a filesystem that, once unmounted, will never be used again. I actually use some extra flags to optimize for my particular workload, but I don't think they're relevant here, so I didn't post them. Anyway, HDD, kernel >= 5.10, mostly sequential reads and writes of medium and large files. Minimal writes to metadata. Shallow directory structure.

Comment: Being said that I see little point in preferring `ext4` over `ext2` when journaling features are not desired… increasing the blocksize (if your arch permits > 4K page size) is the way to follow. Most impressive performance boosts that can be observed thanks to ext4 features or mount options (fast_commit, barriers…) mainly concern jbd2 so would not apply in your specific case.

Comment: @MC68020 You don't think delayed allocation and extents are worth it?

Comment: These would depend on a workload you haven't described enough. Files continuously growing in size ? frequent deletions ? applications taking care to fsync on their own etc. Not to say that each one of these features would be worth a separate topic. In particular the delayed allocation feature that I would personally be so incapable to summarize that I resorted to benchmarks resulting in 2 of my 5 fs being mounted nodelalloc ;-)

Comment: I could describe the workload, but I worry it would lead to getting side-tracked with features unrelated to reliability. I'll edit my question to add a bit more detail. Anyway, I benchmarked ext2 and ext4 without a journal, and the latter performed better in almost every respect.

Comment: If you did benchmark, then **you** are right ! necessarily !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141990/discussion-between-forest-and-mc68020).